# What is the Beracha on Goji Berries?

Tags: blessing, fruits

What is the beracha on [goji berries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goji)? I tried looking at websites online but I could not find it anywhere online.

Comment: It seems that it's not that trivial: https://en.toraland.org.il/beit-midrash/articles/orlah-neta-revay/orlah-and-goji-berries/

Answer (score 2):

According to the excellent [article cited by @Kazi b](http://%5Bhttps://en.toraland.org.il/beit-midrash/articles/orlah-neta-revay/orlah-and-goji-berries/) there is debate over whether the Goji Berry bush is halachically considered a tree or a vegetable. The Shulchan Aruch rules that in all such cases where we are unsure whether ha'eitz or ha'adamah would be the proper blessing, we use ha'adamah, which l'chatchila covers vegetables and b'devied covers tree fruits, in application of the basic principle of "safek bracha laquel".
As such, "boray peree ha'adama" is the proper blessing to say over Goji Berries.
From the article cited by @Kazi,

"Trees vs. Vegetables
Classifying a plant as a tree as opposed to a vegetable (a "bush" is not a distinct halachic category) relates to several areas of halacha:

The blessing: ha'eitz or ha'adama (although in this case, when there is a doubt we say ha'adama, which, bedi'avad, also covers trees)."